# How to pattern match an association?

Tags: pattern-matching, associations

I have the following:

```
Clear[a, b];
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 2, 5}, {6, 7, 8}};
b = GroupBy[a, #[[2]] &];

b
```

whose output is:

```
<| 2 -> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 2, 5}}, 7 -> {{6, 7, 8}} |>
```

But how do I construct a pattern for `b`?  I have been taking stabs in the dark, but nothing has worked so far.

```
MatchQ[b, _Association[_Integer -> {__Integer} ..]] (* False *)

MatchQ[b, _Association[Key[_Integer] -> {__Integer} ..]] (* False *)
```

Since the stars in the universe will likely burn out before I have exhausted all the combinatorial possibilities, I would be grateful for some help.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  So, I guess this is not possible in Mathematica.

Comment: why don't you change Association to list of rules? MatchQ[Normal[b], List[_Rule ..]]